# Android: Items of ListView in ListFragment overlaps over themselves

Tags: android, android-listview, android-fragments

I am solving a weird issue with ListFragments.
I have a simple FragmentActivity with one FrameLayout witch is a container for my ListFragment. I use my custom adapter for the data. Everything is diplaying fine until I rotate the device to change the orientation. After that the listview is displyed twice - one list is overlaping the second. When I scroll the list, only one of the lists is moving and it creates artefacts as shown at the picture.

[image: screenshot from emulator]

I initilize the adapter in onCreateActivity and I dont do anything in onDestroy method. Is there anything I should do in onDestroy method to clear the list. Please did you ever met this issue ? I really dont know what to do with it.

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sorry that I didn't append a code, but I really didn't know which part could do this. But I finally figured out what is the cause.

In onCreate method of parent activity I've created a fragment by calling

```
if(mFragment == null)
{
    mFragment = onCreatePane();

    getSupportFragmentManager()
        .beginTransaction()
        .add(R.id.root_container,mFragment)
        .commit();
}
```

I thought that the test for `null` is sufficient. but the fragment content stays in the FrameLayout either after onDestroy is called in Activity (by rotating the device). This is weird, isn't it ?

I tried to put this code to `onStop()`

```
if(mFragment != null)
{
    getSupportFragmentManager()
        .beginTransaction()
        .remove(mFragment)
        .commit();
}
```

but the result was the same. The only solution I found is to replace `add()` method by `replace()` method. But does anybody know why removing of fragment didn't help ? And why the content of fragment remains in FrameLayout after destruction of Activity ?

Thanks again.

EDIT:

Now I know what was the problem. I should test `savedStateInstance == null` instead of `mFragment == null`. If I do not, the main activity will restore old Fragment from saved state and it will create also new Fragment in my onCreate method.